# Latex footnote in figure caption creates too much space between figure and following text

Tags: captions, footnotes

I would like to insert a footnote in in the caption of a figure. To be more precise, the footnote number should be inside the figure caption, while the footnote text should be at the end of the page where the figure appears.
So far the only solution I have found is the following one:

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}
   \caption{bla bla Source \protect\footnotemark}
   \label{fig:my_fig}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{bla bla bla}
Other text under the figure
```

The problem is that in this way it creates a space between the figure and the "Other text under the figure", which is not present if I remove the footnote and that doesn't make sense.
Is there any solution?

edit: I am noticing that this space is not always present, it depends on the text that there is before and after the image. But there is another problem: sometimes the footnote is displayed on the previous page

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The problem may be glue.  Do you have a large unbreakable box starting the next page?